# Entity Framework generated classes: Two objects of the same type are always equal after changes

Tags: entity-framework-5, webforms, ef-database-first

I'm trying to compare two objects of the same type to see if changes where made.
Let me explain the process:

A form is populated on page load. When the form is filled, i save it's original data in a session variable:

```
newForm = FormRegistry.GetData(userID);
Session["oldForm"] = newForm;
```

When the form is saved after some changes, i then compare the two objects and they are always the same.
The data stored in Session["oldForm"] is identical to the newForm object that has the changes.

I'm using Entity Framework and generated the objects using database first. This only happens with objects that have 1-N relationship. This processes works perfectly with objects without any relationship.

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What exactly are these mystical objects? Seriously, could do with a bit more data to analyze this one. Depending on the objects and what logic is applied to compare them there could be any number of reasons.

Comment: hi Mark, here is the class that was generated by EF and some more detailed examples of what i'm doing (or trying to do): http://pastebin.com/75j5xjU7
this only happens with objects created with classes that have 1-n relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay think I have more of an appreciation of what is going - but may be wrong. I initially though you where saving the data between requests creating a new object each time to and doing some sort of comparison on that.

From what it sounds like you are working with the comparing the form data before and after save within the same request. Either way it sounds like because you are actually storing a reference to your object you are effectively comparing the same object with itself.

I think you need to look at getting a clone of the object to compare. Serialisation may be one easy way to create a copy of the object if they are able.

This thread may help: [Deep Copy of a C# Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074381/deep-copy-of-a-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick ideas - firstly I found comparing complex objects with the == operator doesn't work too well, should use `object1.Equals(object2)` - and then you need to implement (i.e. override) the Equals() method, basically iterating through the properties and comparing each.

Also, nulls get in the way. You need to check this case explicitly. This ref is useful [MSDN: Guidelines for Overloading Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have a method to compare both the objects, and its working well (i'm using reflection)