# Removing element from collection caused removing it from all related objects/collections

Tags: c#

Here is my code c#

```
 List<Element> TMPElementsX = new List<Element>();
 TMPElementsX = TMPElements;
 ResultsElements.Add(TMPElementsX);
 Element ee = element;
 TMPElements.Remove(ee);
```

When I removed ee, it leads to removed it also from other collection {TMPElementsX },How can I keep a copy of ee in the **TMPElementsX** .
I need to keep a copy from ee object inside another temporary collection which is **TMPElementsX**

Comment: You have only one list in memory. Create two list 
List<Element> TMPElementsX = new List<Element>();
List<Element> TMPElements = new List<Element>();

Comment: `TMPElementsX = TMPElements;` after this, both objects will point to the same list. Try to write a copy function just copy the value of the list and create two objects instead of using `=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the objects are pointing to the same memory location, so if you remove it from one of the collections will be removed from the other.

You have to do a deep copy (clone) of the collection.

[This post can be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt).

Comment: Error 1 The type arguments for method  Form1.DeepCopy<T>(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @MikeBluer Could you give us more context about that error please? Which of the solutions of the post did you try? thanks

Comment: I tried 

private static ObservableCollection<T> DeepCopy<T>(ObservableCollection<T> list)
    where T : ICloneable
{
   ObservableCollection<T> newList = new ObservableCollection<T>();
   foreach (T rec in list)
   {
       newList.Add((T)rec.Clone());
   }
   return newList;
}

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744750/generic-method-to-create-deep-copy-of-all-elements-in-a-collection

Comment: Try to use the solutions from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt) that are easier using linq and without generics.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `TMPElementsX = TMPElements;`, you actually assign a reference.

It means that both variables `TMPElements` and `TMPElementsX` point at the same object. Removing an object using any of these variables will affect this object.

If you want it to be different and independent `List`s with the same values then you can clone your `List`.

If would be much easier if you had a `List` of value-types (like `int`, `double` etc.). It would be this way:

```
List<int> TMPElementsX = new List<int>();
TMPElementsX = new List<int>(TMPElements); // new list created
ResultsElements.Add(TMPElementsX);
int ee = element;
TMPElements.Remove(ee);
```

However, in case of reference-types copy constructor creates the **new** list with the **same** referenced items. You will need to make a deep copy of a List. You can read some articles at StackOverflow to learn how to make a deep copy:

[How do I clone a generic list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c)
[Generic method to create deep copy of all elements in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744750/generic-method-to-create-deep-copy-of-all-elements-in-a-collection)

In some cases, making a deep copy can be a bad choice. It's kind of hack but not solution. Probably, you can change your architecture and logics to work without it.

Comment: when I make a deep copy, I can't compare if the collection exist because id changes with the new copy

Comment: Why there is no concept like Collection.Copy() or Collection.Clone() ,etc... to make deep copy